# Can't disable swap partition on USB persistence ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: live-usb, swap

I created an ext2 partition for swap and I got it working fine.  I'm new and just wanted to try it.  But I don't want to blow up the USB flash, so I tried to disable it and it's not possible!  I try `sudo nano /etc/fstab`, and comment the line for swap:

```
#/dev/sdb2 swap swap defaults 0 0
```

But it always comes back when I reboot.  I tried deleting the line altogether, and it comes back.  Frustrated, I even deleted the fstab file and it came back when I boot!

I verify the changes are being saved...I boot another USB drive with 10.04 and mount the 14.04.  My changes are there!  But when I boot, something is undoing the changes.  What is doing this and how do I stop it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have encountered one of the limitations of a persistent USB install.   You should be able to add

```
swapoff -a
```

to the /etc/rc.local file somewhere before the "exit 0" line to turn it off.
Or just delete the swap partition.